# Issue with subscribing from JAVA to ROS

Tags: java, c++, lua, ros, torch

I got a JAVA program that saves images produced by an ASUS Xtion Pro Live camera, I want to send the path name where the images are stored to the KUKA youBOT. After the youBOT finishes moving the arm I want to send that path name to Torch. The path name is in this form "/home/.../classes/100.jpg".

The JAVA code is:

```
            if(xxx!=0){
                Highgui.imwrite(x1+"-.jpg", out); 
                String name = "/home/isa/Downloads/java_rosbridge/target/classes/" + x1 + ".jpg";
                System.out.println("name:" + x1);
                String name1 = String.valueOf(x1);
                pubname.publish(new PrimitiveMsg<String>(name1));
                String ttttx=String.valueOf(XXXX);
                String tttty=String.valueOf(YYYY);
                String ttttz=String.valueOf(ZZZZ);
                pubx.publish(new PrimitiveMsg<String>(ttttx));
                puby.publish(new PrimitiveMsg<String>(tttty));
                pubz.publish(new PrimitiveMsg<String>(ttttz));
                delay(500);
                //Highgui.imwrite(x1+"-.jpg", out2);  
                //System.exit(0);
                System.out.println(name);
            }
```

The c++ code for the youBOT is:

```
double x;
double y;
double z;
double name; 

void chatterCallbackName(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) {
    const char *namestring = msg->data.c_str();
    name = atof(namestring);
    ROS_INFO("Name Callback: %s",name);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    bool booleanname;

    ros::init(argc, argv, "moveit_test");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
    spinner.start();

    // The :move_group_interface:`MoveGroup` class can be easily setup using just the name of the group you would like to control and plan for.
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("arm_1");

    // print the name of the reference frame for this robot.
    ROS_INFO("Reference frame: %s", group.getPlanningFrame().c_str());

    // print the name of the end-effector link for this group.
    std::string endEffector = group.getEndEffectorLink();
    ROS_INFO("Reference frame: %s", endEffector.c_str());

    const robot_state::JointModelGroup* joint_model_group = group.getCurrentState()->getRobotModel()->getJointModelGroup(group.getName());

    float phi [] = {-180, -180, 0}; //154
    float theta [] = {-90, -67, 160}; //90
    float psi [] = {0, -6, -5}; //39

    ros::Subscriber subname = n.subscribe("xtionname", 1000, chatterCallbackName);




/*

    ros::Subscriber subxl = n.subscribe("luax", 1000, chatterCallbackx);
    ros::Subscriber subyl = n.subscribe("luay", 1000, chatterCallbacky);
    ros::Subscriber subzl = n.subscribe("luaz", 1000, chatterCallbackz);
*/
    for (int iter=0; iter<2; ++iter)
    {
        bool boolean;




        phi[iter] = phi[iter] * (M_PI/180); theta[iter] = theta[iter] * (M_PI/180); psi[iter] = psi[iter] * (M_PI/180);

        float qx = cos(phi[iter]/2)*cos(theta[iter]/2)*cos(psi[iter]/2) + sin(phi[iter]/2)*sin(theta[iter]/2)*sin(psi[iter]/2);
        float qy = sin(phi[iter]/2)*cos(theta[iter]/2)*cos(psi[iter]/2) - cos(phi[iter]/2)*sin(theta[iter]/2)*sin(psi[iter]/2);
        float qz = cos(phi[iter]/2)*sin(theta[iter]/2)*cos(psi[iter]/2) + sin(phi[iter]/2)*cos(theta[iter]/2)*sin(psi[iter]/2);
        float qw = cos(phi[iter]/2)*cos(theta[iter]/2)*sin(psi[iter]/2) - sin(phi[iter]/2)*sin(theta[iter]/2)*cos(psi[iter]/2);

        const double des_posX[] = {0.35, 0.35 + x, 0.18652}; // , , 0.543175
        const double des_posY[] = {-0.05, -y, -0.00384585}; // , , -0.0720582
        const double des_posZ[] = {0.25, 0.25 - z, 0.371596}; // , , 0.161611
        const double des_orientX[] = {qx, qx, qx}; // -0.03369, 0.0670559, 0.0384911, -0.00385598
        const double des_orientY[] = {qy, qy, qy}; // 0.834522, 0.712052, 0.405772, 0.17666
        const double des_orientZ[] = {qz, qz, qz}; // -0.0442666, -0.0783854, -0.0863349, -0.211289
        const double des_orientW[] = {qw, qw, qw}; // 0.548158, 0.694508, 0.909073, 0.961319





        // current pose
        geometry_msgs::PoseStamped target_pose1 = group.getCurrentPose();

        ROS_INFO("Current position:    x: %f, y: %f, z: %f", target_pose1.pose.position.x, target_pose1.pose.position.y, target_pose1.pose.position.z);
        ROS_INFO("Current orientation: x: %f, y: %f, z: %f, w: %f", target_pose1.pose.orientation.x, target_pose1.pose.orientation.y, target_pose1.pose.orientation.z, target_pose1.pose.orientation.w);

        // goal pose
        target_pose1.pose.position.x = des_posX[iter];
        target_pose1.pose.position.y = des_posY[iter];
        target_pose1.pose.position.z = des_posZ[iter];
        target_pose1.pose.orientation.x = des_orientX[iter];
        target_pose1.pose.orientation.y = des_orientY[iter];
        target_pose1.pose.orientation.z = des_orientZ[iter];
        target_pose1.pose.orientation.w = des_orientW[iter];

        ROS_INFO("Target position:    x: %f, y: %f, z: %f", target_pose1.pose.position.x, target_pose1.pose.position.y, target_pose1.pose.position.z);
        ROS_INFO("Target orientation: x: %f, y: %f, z: %f, w: %f", target_pose1.pose.orientation.x, target_pose1.pose.orientation.y, target_pose1.pose.orientation.z, target_pose1.pose.orientation.w);

        // directly call IK here
        bool ik_success = group.setJointValueTarget(target_pose1, endEffector);
        ROS_INFO("IK %s",ik_success?"SUCCESS":"FAILURE");

        if (ik_success)
        {
            std::vector<double> joint_values;

            group.getCurrentState()->copyJointGroupPositions(joint_model_group, joint_values);
            ROS_INFO("Current joint: %f %f %f %f %f", joint_values[0], joint_values[1], joint_values[2], joint_values[3], joint_values[4]);

            group.getJointValueTarget().copyJointGroupPositions(joint_model_group, joint_values);
            ROS_INFO("Target joint:  %f %f %f %f %f", joint_values[0], joint_values[1], joint_values[2], joint_values[3], joint_values[4]);

            // now we could also just directly send the desired joint positions to the robot

            // just planning, not moving the robot yet
            moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan my_plan;
            bool plan_success = group.plan(my_plan);

            ROS_INFO("Planning %s",plan_success?"SUCCESS":"FAILURE");   

            if (plan_success)
            {
                // move robot
                group.move();
                // sleep(5.0);

                target_pose1 = group.getCurrentPose();

                ROS_INFO("Current position:    x: %f, y: %f, z: %f", target_pose1.pose.position.x, target_pose1.pose.position.y, target_pose1.pose.position.z);
                ROS_INFO("Current orientation: x: %f, y: %f, z: %f, w: %f", target_pose1.pose.orientation.x, target_pose1.pose.orientation.y, target_pose1.pose.orientation.z, target_pose1.pose.orientation.w);

                group.getCurrentState()->copyJointGroupPositions(joint_model_group, joint_values);
                ROS_INFO("Current joint: %f %f %f %f %f", joint_values[0], joint_values[1], joint_values[2], joint_values[3], joint_values[4]);


    publish();
    ROS_INFO("Name: %s",name);

    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("path", 1000);

                ros::Publisher bool_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("bool", 1000);
                boolean = 1;
                while (boolean == 1) {
                    std_msgs::String msg;
                        std::stringstream ss;
                        ss << name;
                        msg.data = ss.str();
                    chatter_pub.publish(msg);
                    ROS_INFO("Path: %s",msg.data.c_str());
                    ROS_INFO("Path2: %s",name);
                    booleanname = 0;



                    std_msgs::String msgbool;
                        std::stringstream ssbool;
                        ssbool << "Hallo";
                        msgbool.data = ssbool.str();
                    bool_pub.publish(msgbool);
                    boolean = 0;
                } 


            }
        }
    }
    ros::spin();
    // END_TUTORIAL
    //ros::shutdown(); 
    //return 0;
}
```

The Torch code is:

```
-- plaatjes binnenkrijgen en commando's versturen
--while true do
bool = Hallo
while (bool == Hallo) do    
subscribery = nodehandle:subscribe("bool", 'std_msgs/String', 100)
      sys.sleep(0.1)
  while subscribery:hasMessage() do
    bool = subscribery:read()
    print(bool)
  end 
--function sleep(n)
 -- os.execute("sleep " .. tonumber(n+1))
--end
end

int = 1
while int < 2 do
subscriberx = nodehandle:subscribe("xtionname", 'std_msgs/String', 100)
  while subscriberx:hasMessage() do
msg = subscriberx:read()
print(msg)
  end
    int = int+1
end

sys.sleep(30.0)
string1 = "/home/isa/Downloads/java_rosbridge/target/classes/"
string2 = "500"
string3 = ".jpg"
plaatje = image.load(string1 .. msg .. string3)
string_specx = ros.MsgSpec('std_msgs/String')
string_specy = ros.MsgSpec('std_msgs/String')
string_specz = ros.MsgSpec('std_msgs/String')

publisherx = nodehandle:advertise("luax", string_specx, 100)
publishery = nodehandle:advertise("luay", string_specy, 100)
publisherz = nodehandle:advertise("luaz", string_specz, 100)

x = ros.Message(string_specx)
y = ros.Message(string_specy)
z = ros.Message(string_specz)

function run(n)
for i = 1,100 do  
    if not ros.ok() then
      return
    end
    if publisherx:getNumSubscribers() == 0 and publishery:getNumSubscribers() == 0 and publisherz:getNumSubscribers() == 0  then
      print('waiting for subscriber')
    else
      x.data = string.format("%.7f", net:forward(plaatje)[1])
      y.data = string.format("%.7f", net:forward(plaatje)[2])
      z.data = string.format("%.7f", net:forward(plaatje)[3])
      publisherx:publish(x)
      publishery:publish(y)
      publisherz:publish(z)
    return
    end
    sys.sleep(0.1)
    ros.spinOnce()
  end
end

run(100)
--end
ros.shutdown()
```

Whenever I read the path name from the youBOT program, the output is some kind of gibberish, i.e. ??!!G@@!!. However, if I apply a rostopic echo to it, I get the path name without issues. Also, if I print the path name at the CallBack function in the youBOT program I also get an expected output.

I can't get it to work somehow. Can somebody help me?